# @media запрос не меняет размер шрифта

Tags: html, css, sass

сделал шапку сайта на flex, затем через медиа запрос при уменьшении экрана хочу уменьшить шрифт, но он не уменьшается, в консоли просто строка зачеркнута

```
.hero
    &-wrap
        display: flex
        justify-content: space-between
    &__title
        flex-basis: 45%
        &-heading
            text-transform: uppercase
            font-size: 60px
            margin-bottom: 35px
        & p
            font-size: 16px
```

@media (max-width: 1279px)

```
.hero
    &-wrap
        flex-direction: column
    &__title
        flex-basis: 100%
        &-heading
            font-size: 20px
```

(код нормально не хотел отображаться, сделал перенос после медиа, а так он нормально прописан)

проблема - шрифт не становится 20 пикселей

Comment: Проблему решил. на этом отрезке кода ее не видно, проблема была в лишней табуляции от .hero до самого медиа запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, находятся ли ваши медиа-запросы после основных стилей, иначе они будут переписаны. Также рекомендую поиграться с !important, таким образом вы поймете, проблема с специфичности или же в ошибке в коде

Comment: медиа запрос в самом низу.
прописал !important и это сработало, но почему без этого не срабатывает...
в консоли перечёркивается, как я уже сказал

Comment: Значит проблема в специфичности селекторов. Селектор, который вы используете до медиа-запроса более специфичен, чем тот, который используете в теле медиа-запроса. Почитайте про специфичность селекторов и все станет на свои места)